# php explode where no spaces etc

Tags: php, explode

I am trying to explode a string that does not already define the parts clearly (i.e. with spaces or commas)

example string : FRPARGBASD

the FR PAR GB ASD all need to be exploded to insert as seperate entities into a database.

How would I go about this please

Comment: What's the logic of this tokenization ? Why not FRP A RGBAS D ?

Comment: You can't split anything without knowing the pattern. Is it 2/3/2/3 characters? Is it split based on the content?

Comment: Do you want to split the text into 2 chars - 3 chars - 2 chars - 3 chars etc... ?

Comment: I guess that the length of the first token is `floor(sqrt(string_length))-1` but I don't find the logic for the next token.

Comment: you should explain the logic behind the split in your question

Comment: Thanks have solved this by sing a split $from = str_split("$data[14]",5);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming those are location names "France", "Paris", "Great Britain", etc...

Here is one possible solution:

```
$places = array("FR", "PAR", "GB", "ASD");
$string = "FRPARGBASD";

$tokens = array();
while (strlen($string) > 0) {
   $next_token = "";
   $i = 0;
   while ($next_token == "") {
      if (substr($string, 0, strlen($places[$i])) == $places[$i]) {
         $next_token = $places[$i];
      }
   }
   $tokens[] = $next_token;
   $string = substr($string, strlen($next_token));
}

var_dump($tokens);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm not sure that it's good practice to guess what OP wants, especially in the case where he didn't put any effort in to explain. It produces potentially incorrect (and therefore useless and cluttersome) answers, and promotes the idea that people don't need to give us details in order to get what they want.

Comment: Although making this assumption is not enforcing clear question asking, I still feel it could be helpful. Either, the string he is wanting to tokenize is made up of predefined sub-strings, in which case my code can assist in finding the best solution, or the string is made up of random sub-strings, in which case, my suggested code would not solve the problem, but perhaps allow Meohmy to think about a possible solution in a way other than by using explode().

Comment: Perhaps, but it would have been significantly more prudent to draft an answer in pre-emption of his clarification, then choose whether to submit it (or a modified version of it) based on his response.

Comment: haha nice one ! +1 @ralfe for recognizing the "pattern"